# C Program, having trouble traversing singly linked list for pop function

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to make a linked list which can be accessed by a push, pop and full function. I believe that I've created the push function correctly, but I'm having trouble implementing the pop. I think I have found the error, I am unable to traverse through the linked list with my while loop.

Here is my push function:

```
int push(char x){
if(full() == 1) return 1;
else if(full() == 0){
    last = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    aNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    aNode -> next = anchor;
    anchor = aNode;
    aNode -> data = x;
    last -> data = aNode -> data;
    last -> next = aNode -> next;
    return 0;
}
else{
    aNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    aNode -> next = anchor;
    anchor = aNode;
    aNode -> data = x;
    last -> data = aNode -> data;
    last -> next = aNode -> next;
    return 0;
}
```

My pop function is:

```
int pop(){
if(full() == 0) return 0;
else{
    curr_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    store = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    curr_ptr = anchor;

    while(curr_ptr != NULL){
        curr_ptr = curr_ptr -> next;
    }

    store -> next = '\0';
    store -> data = last -> data;
    last -> next = curr_ptr -> next;
    last -> data = curr_ptr -> data;
    free(curr_ptr);
    return store -> data;

}
```

I get a segmentation fault at the while loop. I tried an alternate while loop which did not cause any errors, but never executed in the code for some reason. I threw a printf statement in the loop and it never printed anything. That loop was:

```
    while(curr_ptr -> next != NULL){
        curr_ptr = curr_ptr -> next;
    }
```

Comment: You caused memory leak in `curr_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); curr_ptr = anchor;` Don't allocate what you don't need.

Comment: "I get a segmentation fault at the while loop." Are you sure? if yes, it *may be* because invalid pointer (uninitialized or already freed) is assigned to `curr_ptr -> next`. If no, `last -> next = curr_ptr -> next;` has a big chance to cause Segmentation Fault for dereferencing `NULL`. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help detecting the problem.

Comment: You should use `fflush(stdout);` after every call of `printf();` for debugging to make sure what is passed to `printf()` is printed.

Comment: Also note that using global variables isn't a good idea unless it is necessary.

Comment: no... i think that code no works for push neither pop. Or you must post more code

Comment: While Mike may be willing to create a program to debug your code, you should provide a *Minimum Complete Verifiable Example*. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." You will get more help that way.

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not be surrounded by spaces in conventionally written C.

Comment: How does `full()` work?  It seems to return 3 values (0, 1 and something else).  Why do you allocate a node for `last`?  How is `anchor` initialized?  Why are you allocating the space for `store`?  It (almost certainly) gets leaked.  Writing `store->next = '\0';` is an aconventional way of writing `store->next = 0;` or `store->next = NULL:`.  (Aconventional means "not actually wrong, but not the way that most people write it, and for good reason".)  I think you should assume that each of `push()`, `pop()` and `full()` is wrong and start over.   Draw diagrams of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You never assign `last` in `pop`, but you loop for it. Replace your `while(curr_ptr/*...*/` loop with
`for (last=anchor; last->next; last=last->next);` automatically jumps `last` to the last list member.
But your double-free comes from

```
curr_ptr = anchor;
/* ... */
free(curr_ptr);
```

while `curr_ptr` does not point to the `malloc`ed memory but to `anchor`, which is quite likely part of your list and should not be freed.
As Mike said, curr_ptr should allocate memory, when it just should point into the list.
Actually there is no reason to allocate anything in a `pop` function!

Edit for the comment: Just as an example about list structures, based on your example

```
struct Node {
    char data;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct List {
    struct Node* head;
    struct Node* tail;
};
int push(struct List* L, char c);
int pop(struct List* L);
```

Next you can define your functions basically (whatever full might mean).

```
int push(struct List* L, char c)
{
    if (L->head == NULL) {
        L->head = L->tail = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        L->head->data = x;
    } else {
        L->tail->next = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        L->tail = L->tail->next;
        L->tail->data = x;
    }
    return 1;
}
int pop(struct List* L)
{
    struct Node* cur = NULL;
    if (L->head == NULL) {
        return 0; /* nothing to remove */
    } else if (L->head == L->tail) {
        free(L->head);
        L->head = L->tail = NULL; /* the list is empty now */
    } else {
        for (cur = L->head; cur->next != L->tail; cur = cur->next);
        cur->next = NULL;
        free(L->tail);
        L->tail = cur;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now you can start to specialize for your needs.

Comment: I've read through everyone's help and I realize I had a lot of junk in there that I did not need. After I cleaned it up I get:

    curr_ptr = anchor;
    for (last=anchor; last->next; last=last->next);
    store = last;
    last = anchor;
    return store->data;

Which just returns the first value every time. I can not wrap my head around this. I've tried drawing a picture, and I think I understand what pointers to move, but I just can't seem to get it.

Comment: actually there is no reason to have last AND curr_ptr. Either you use curr_ptr to move through your list or last. You really just have too many variables and you seem to be lost in your data. Maybe it would be best to start with a minimal example. Also note that we don't use global data in our days but structures to a list for push and pop for example, that hold head and tail pointers for example